# Writing My Prolog Code

Tags: prolog

I am writing my first Prolog code, and I am have some difficulties with it I was wondering if anyone could help me out.

I am writing a program that needs to follow the following rules:

for Verb phrases., noun phrases come before transitive verbs. 
subjects (nominative noun phrases) are followed by ga
Direct Objects (nominative noun phrases are followed by o.

it must be able to form these sentences with the given words in the code:
Adamu ga waraimasu (adam laughs) 
Iive ga nakimasu (eve cries) 
Adamu ga Iivu O mimasi (adam watches Eve) 
Iivu ga Adamu O tetsudaimasu (eve helps adam)

here is my code. It it mostly complete except, I don't know if the rules are correct in the code:

```
Japanese([adamu ],[nounphrase],[adam],[entity]).
Japanese([iivu  ],[nounphrase],[eve],[entity]).
Japanese([waraimasu  ],[verb,intransitive],[laughs],[property]).
Japanese([nakimasu],[verb,intransitive],[cries],[property]).
Japanese([mimasu ],[verb,transitive],[watches],[relation]).
Japanese([tetsudaimasu  ],[verb,transitive],[helps],[relation]).
Japanese(A,[verbphrase],B,[property]):-
   Japanese(A,[verb,intransitive],B,[property]).
Japanese(A,[nounphrase,accusative],B,[entity]):-
   Japanese(C,[nounphrase],B,[entity]),
   append([ga],C,A).
Japanese(A,[verbphrase],B,[property]):-
   Japanese(C,[verb,transitive],D,[relation]),
   Japanese(E,[nounphrase,accusative],F,[entity]),
   append(C,E,A),
   append(D,F,B).
Japanese(A,[sentence],B,[proposition]):-
   Japanese(C,[nounphrase],D,[entity]),
   Japanese(E,[verbphrase],F,[property]),
   append(E,C,A),
   append(F,D,B).
```

Comment: Your first program? Try a smaller one!

Comment: First of all, a syntax issue. In Prolog, predicate names must be an atom so cannot begin with a capital letter. You'll need to change `Japanes` to `japanese`. Second, this isn't a well-formed question for this site. You're just saying, "here's my code and wondering if it's correct". You'll need to work with your code, do some debugging, and ask more specific questions about errors or unexpected results. And, I agree with @false, for a first program you should practice on something much simpler to get the hang of it.

Comment: Also, use DCG for this type of problem. (It's in the manual.)

Comment: Why is everything in lists? Where are your facts that let you identify words as nouns, subjects or verbs to begin with? The post is also poorly written, making everything even more confusing. Please clean up.